# How do I open interface overview on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I was watching a VSC tutorial I noticed an interface overview feature, what I understood it as was that it acted as a small helper, so that when you hovered over something it would give an explanation of what is does, I may be wrong. But, when I reopened VSC th option didn't apear anymore as it did when I first opened thee application.

Comment: **Help** | **Getting Started**, or any of the other Help menu option